# How to add a subview/view in Charts Pie chart?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios13

Im using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) for iOS and I need to add a custom view inside the circle of the pie chart the library supports only text inside, is that possible ? with auto layout in mind for multi screen size support

[image: Pie chart image]

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to add a custom view inside the circle, but if you would rephrase it to "have some custom view to appear within the circle", then you can solve it by having your custom view **above** the pie chart. (In storyboard editor, put the custom view after the chart)

Then, use Auto-layout constraints to make it look great for all screens. E.g. Align custom view & pie vertical/horizontal centers or other relevant constraint types.